# RMI using spring. Executing method in server with object as parameter

Tags: rmi

I am trying to execute a method from client to server using RMI. 
As long as the parameters are String, it is getting executed correctly. If I am using object as method parameter.

I am getting following exception :

java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)

Server configuration:

```
@Bean
public RmiServiceExporter getUserService() {
    RmiServiceExporter exporter = new RmiServiceExporter();
    exporter.setService(userService);
    exporter.setServiceName("UserService");
    exporter.setServiceInterface(UserService.class);
    exporter.setRegistryPort(1192);
    exporter.setReplaceExistingBinding(true);
    return exporter;
}
```

Client configuration:

```
public @Bean RmiProxyFactoryBean getUserService() {
    RmiProxyFactoryBean rmi = new RmiProxyFactoryBean();
    rmi.setServiceInterface(UserService.class);
    rmi.setServiceUrl("rmi://localhost:1192/UserService");
    return rmi;
}
```

Test code :

```
User user = userService.getUser(String userName);
```

Works perfectly fine.

```
userService.save(user);
```

Save user throws RMI exception.

I made sure that the package name for User object in server and client is same. Still I am getting the exception.
Am I missing any configuration? How can I make RMI server to load the other classes?

Comment: does User implement Serializable interface?

Comment: Yes.  User class implements Serializable.